# iText7 & C# extract pages from PDF stored in MSSQL DB

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I have a PDF document already stored in the database.  It's stored as an "image" datatype (I had no choice with that). I'm working in C# .NET with iText 7, and the database is MSSQL. I want to parse that database data into smaller sections of that file.  I don't have the original PDF file, only the image stored in the database.

I want to separate the original PDF data (image) into pages.  That is, if we had the original file, I want to split that large file by every 2 pages into new files (e.g., a 10 page PDF would become 5 files, 2 pages each).  I want to then store those smaller "PDFs" into the databases as well.

Is there any way to do this entirely in code?  Or do I need to create a PDF file in the file system, and then create new files based on the file, and then import the individual files back into the database?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Read about MemoryStream, that can hold your data without creating the file. Example,

```
// database part here
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
if (dr.Read())
{
    byte[] pdf = (byte[])dr["image_pdf"];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picarr);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // PDF part here
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
    doc.Open();
    ...
```